# ANDROID: Searching SQLite db for rows having 3 columns with equal values

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Im trying to search a table (TABLE1) to get rows that have the same values per column (amount, dayofweek and category). I would then like to copy those rows into a new table (TABLE2).

```
TABLE1

rowid || AMOUNT  || DAYOFWEEK  || CATEGORY  ||    DATE
------------------------------------------------------------
1     ||    30   ||    MON     ||    CAT1   ||  10/04/2017
2     ||    40   ||    TUE     ||    CAT4   ||  11/04/2017
3     ||    30   ||    MON     ||    CAT1   ||  18/04/2017
4     ||    50   ||    SUN     ||    CAT2   ||  23/04/2017


TABLE2 (DESIRED OUTCOME)

rowid || AMOUNT  || DAYOFWEEK  || CATEGORY  ||     DATE
------------------------------------------------------------
  1   ||    30   ||    MON     ||    CAT1   ||  10/04/2017
  2   ||    30   ||    MON     ||    CAT1   ||  18/04/2017
```

From the scenario above I would like to copy content from rows 1 and 3 from TABLE1 and insert them into TABLE2. Any suggestions on how i could could code this for SQLite on Android?

Answer (score -1):

You can use sql syntax to do an insert into `TABLE2` by selecting duplicates from `TABLE1`, something like below (*have not tested*) :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (AMOUNT, DAYOFWEEK, CATEGORY)
SELECT
    AMOUNT, DAYOFWEEK, CATEGORY
FROM
    TABLE1
GROUP BY
    AMOUNT, DAYOFWEEK, CATEGORY
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

**Or**

you can use the select above pouplate an `ArrayList` of `object` class and do an insert using that `ArrayList`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work I keep getting this error when i try the above

Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 4 values for 3 columns (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO...

Comment: You don't need the count in the SELECT clause.

Comment: try now, removed count from select clause